# Find InstallShield version used for creating an ISM file

Tags: windows-installer, installation, installshield

I have an old ism file that I am trying to open. But I don't know what version of Installshield was used for creating the ISM project. Is there a way to tell this from the ISM file?

I'm seeing some issues when I upgrade the ISM file.

Answer (score 13):

Open the ISM file with a text editor and look for "SchemaVersion".

```
755 = DevStudio 9 (Erstwhile name of InstallShield)
761 = IS11
763 = IS11.5 
765 = IS12 
766 = IS2008 
768 = IS2009 
769 = IS2010 
770 = IS2010
771 = IS2011
772 = IS2012
774 = IS2013
775 = IS2014
776 = IS2015
777 = IS2016
778 = IS2018 R1
779 = IS2018 R2
780 = IS2019
783 = IS2020 R1
784 = IS2020 R2/R3
787 = IS2022 R2
789 = IS2023 R2
```

You may be able to use your version of IS if you change the value.  [See this discussion](https://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?181825-Can-t-open-setup-ism).

Comment: I see schema version 771. So I guess this is IS 2011.

Comment: Yup, just added 2011/2012 values.  Hope this helps!

Comment: For more historical details of InstallShield releases please check [Links to InstallShield Downloads and Documentation](https://zzz.buzz/notes/links-to-installshield-downloads-and-documentation/) & [InstallShield Lifecycle Timeline](https://docs.revenera.com/eol/installshield.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot open a 770 ism, install installshield 2010 sp1, then try again.